# SQLServer Subquery units as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a subquery as a column with a condition.

The error I get from SQL Server is:

**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

There are a bunch more columns I'm selecting, but here is the main query that is giving ma an error:

```
SELECT ItemNo, Channel, Brand, TotalUnits,
       (SELECT TotalUnits FROM Table1 WHERE Locked = 1) As LockedUnits
FROM Table1
```

*EDIT: Locked is a 0 or 1 value*

Ideally the query would return this (LockedUnits is always a subset of TotalUnits):

```
ItemNO   Channel   Brand    TotalUnits    LockedUnits
1        5         Adidas   100           80
2        7         Nike     500           360
```

Comment: I think you must clarify your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is get `TotalUnits` only for those rows where `Locked = 1`. If that's the case, you're better off using `case`:

```
SELECT ItemNo, Channel, Brand, TotalUnits,
       case when Locked = 1 then TotalUnits else null end As LockedUnits
FROM Table1
```

You can use a sub-select to do this, but you need to join the sub-select to the main query. Assuming `ItemNo` is unique, it would look like this:

```
SELECT ItemNo, Channel, Brand, TotalUnits,
       (SELECT TotalUnits FROM Table1 t2 WHERE Locked = 1
        WHERE t1.itemno = t2.itemno) As LockedUnits
FROM Table1 t1
```

Of course, it's kind of silly to hit a single table twice to get values that are already in the row you're returning.

---

Comment Response: The only time you'd prefer the sub-select is if you're getting data from a different table or a different row in the same table. And, even then, I prefer to put the table in the where clause and join it to the main table normally.

Comment: you are awesome, sir!  The "case" option makes more sense to me, would there be any cases (pun not intended) where the sub-select would be preferable?

Answer (score 1):

try putting SELECT sum(TotalUnits) in the subquery

Comment: I already tried that and it outputs the sum of TotalUnits for all items in each row

Answer (score 1):

You have to limit the subquery to a single result, otherwise it cannot be returned in a result set column.  You will need to narrow down your results to a single record by SUM(TotalUnits), SELECT TOP 1, or SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: So the condition "Locked = 1" matches more than once for each row?

Comment: No, it matches once per row but if you have multiple rows matching "locked=1" then it will return them all... unless you have something else limiting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ItemNo, Channel, Brand, TotalUnits,
   (SELECT sum(TotalUnits) FROM Table1 WHERE Locked = 1) As LockedUnits
FROM Table1
group by ItemNo, Channel, Brand, TotalUnits
```